# How to Remove "time elapsed" info from being displayed on console?

Tags: codelite

I'm going through a tutorial which uses CodeLite, and when I build and execute my project, the console displays "time elapsed" info which I don't need right now, and to be honest, it just clutters up the results that I want to see. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm running Windows 10 64-bit. CodeLite version 12.0.0.